# Is this possible to schedule CronJob to execute on each of Kubernetes nodes?

Tags: kubernetes, devops, kubernetes-cronjob

What I would like to do is to run some backup scripts on each of Kubernetes nodes periodically. I want it to run inside Kubernetes cluster in contrast to just adding script to each node's crontab. This is because I will store backup on the volume mounted to the node by Kubernetes. It differs from the configuration but it could be CIFS filesystem mounted by Flex plugin or `awsElasticBlockStore`.

It would be perfect if `CronJob` will be able to template `DaemonSet` (instead of fixing it as `jobTemplate`) and there will be possibility to set `DaemonSet` restart policy to `OnFailure`.

I would like to avoid defining `n` different `CronJobs` for each of `n` nodes and then associate them together by defining `nodeSelectors` since this will be not so convenient to maintain in environment where nodes count changes dynamically.

What I can see problem was discussed here without any clear conclusion: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/36601

Maybe do you have any hacks or tricks to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use DaemonSet with the following bash script:

```
  while :; do
   currenttime=$(date +%H:%M)
   if [[ "$currenttime" > "23:00" ]] && [[ "$currenttime" < "23:05" ]]; then
     do_something
   else
     sleep 60
   fi
   test "$?" -gt 0 && notify_failed_job
  done
```

Comment: This is the most hacky way I can imagine ;) Anyway, it will work.

Do you think that there is no any other more Kubernetes native solution?

Comment: Actually there are some issues (e.g. https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/36601) on k8s GitHub about the problem and there is no native support. At the moment your solution is the most reasonably way to do it so I marked it as accepted.

Comment: on line 3 the || should be an && otherwise do_something is always called

Answer (score 1):

i know i am late to party,

**First option :**

Using the **parallelism** to run multiple Job PODs, with **topologySpreadConstraints** to spread/schedule the PODs on all the nodes.

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: mycronjob
  labels:
    jobgroup: parallel
spec:
  schedule: "*/5 * * * *"
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 0
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        metadata:
          name: kubejob
          labels:
            jobgroup: parallel
        spec:
          topologySpreadConstraints:
            - maxSkew: 2
              topologyKey: kubernetes.io/hostname
              whenUnsatisfiable: DoNotSchedule
              labelSelector:
                matchLabels:
                  jobgroup: parallel
          containers:
          - name: mycron-container
            image: alpine
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command: ['sh', '-c', 'echo Job Pod is Running ; sleep 10']
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
          terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 0
      parallelism: 5
  concurrencyPolicy: Allow
```

**Option two :**

Using **cronjob** you can **apply** the YAML template of **daemon set** and delete it after a certain duration which will work as job ideally on all nodes. Also if a custom docker image runs inside the deamon set it could also be complete once done with execution.

**Extra**:

You can use the **CRD** option checkout my Article which will work like Daemonjob : https://medium.com/google-cloud/daemon-job-crd-in-k8s-with-compositecontroller-f263b7f25cb9

Schedule **job** on each available node.

Read more about the CRD : https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/extend-kubernetes/api-extension/custom-resources/

You can write your own custom resource and add it to the **kuberetes**.